# Post request in node.js does not put the right data into mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this piece of code, it's a part of a larger piece of code that does work with fake data, but now I've connected it to an online database with mongodb and mongoose:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://evivermeeren:wachtwoord@cluster0.ep81pko.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
);

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const messageSchema = new Schema({
  user: String,
  message: String,
});

const Message = mongoose.model("Message", messageSchema);

// Body-parser middleware om JSON-berichten te verwerken
app.use(express.json());

// CORS toestaan
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.post("/api/v1/messages", async (req, res) => {
  const { user, text } = req.body;

  // Create a new message document
  const newMessage = new Message({
    user,
    message: text,
  });

  try {
    // Save the new message to the database
    const savedMessage = await newMessage.save();

    res.json({
      status: "success",
      message: `POSTING a new message for user ${user}`,
      data: {
        message: savedMessage,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Internal Server Error",
    });
  }
});
```

I'm testing it through Postman with this request:

[image]

It's not being put in my database the right way. This is the response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "POSTING a new message for user undefined",
    "data": {
        "message": {
            "_id": "65301dba6aa88558fdfbade7",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
}
```

But it should be something like:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "POSTING a new message for user Arne",
    "data": {
        "message": {
            "_id": "65301dba6aa88558fdfbade7",
            "__v": 0, 
"user": "Arne", 
"text": "This is a text"

        }
    }
}
```

This is how the database looks:

[image]

Comment: Delete your username and password from your connection string in the post. Anyone can use it to connect to your database and cause havoc. Once you have done that change your password.